# Constructing a band structure analog for a system with open boundaries

Tags: quantum-mechanics, boundary-conditions, tight-binding

In systems with periodic boundary conditions, we can use translation invariance to find simultaneous eigenstates of total energy and momentum. With open boundary conditions, this symmetry is destroyed, and the notion of band structure seems to be destroyed. My goal is to find a procedure for generating as faithful a set of momentum states as possible out of the energy eigenstates of a given model.

To be more precise, suppose we consider the simplest possible tight binding model for an electron hopping on $N$ sites. With periodic boundary conditions, we have

$$H = -t\sum_{j=1}^{N}\left(|j\rangle\langle j+1| + |j+1\rangle\langle j|\right)$$

with $|N+1\rangle \equiv |1\rangle$. Then the eigenfunctions are just

$$|k\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{j=1}^{N}e^{ikj}|j\rangle$$

With a band whose energies are $-2t\cos\left(k\right)$, setting the lattice spacing to 1.

Now if we break the translation invariance by making the boundary conditions open and modifying the Hamiltonian appropriately, momentum is no longer a good quantum number. But if we compute the eigenfunctions explicitly, we can always do things like take discrete Fourier transforms and look at the peaks in momentum space. For degenerate states, can we systematically form superpositions which are optimally peaked around a single momentum value, and construct an approximate "band structure" for the open chain?

Comment: You might consider looking at the use of wavelets for basis functions